# Invoke-Command to remote machine leads to COMException (0x80040154)

Tags: c#, powershell, com, invoke-command

I have a C#.NET application that uses COM.

When I call the application locally (machine1), the COM object is created as it should.

When I start the application remotely from another machine (machine2) using

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {path\theapp.exe}
```

the application starts up (on machine1 of course) but fails to bind the COM object:

```
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C4DBE1C1-0608-48DF-AD9D-F34284FE7040} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
```

I do not understand how this is possible -- since the COM connection works if execution is started locally, why would the runtime find out later that the class is not registered?

Thanks for any hints and pointers!

Comment: Have you looked up the HRESULT (0x80040154)? What does that tell you? Have you looked in the event log (`eventvwr.msc`)? What does that tell you?

Comment: event log does not show anythin unusual...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Reason was (1) a mismatch of debug/release versions of components and (2) another component not run as service wehen it should have.

Thanks for reading and posting!